# Field is not displayed in new form of list

Tags: 2013, content-type, column, list-form

I have created a field to add it in the content type and that content type is used in the list.

My field's declarative part is:

```
<!--Field Type of project-->
  <Field ID="{0D3060A0-D1A4-4468-B6D3-411839955928}"
           Name="oiplbProjectType"
           StaticName="oiplbProjectType"
           DisplayName="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectTypeDisplayName;"
           Description="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectTypeDescription;"
           Type="Choice"
           Required="TRUE"
           Format="Dropdown"
           ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
           ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
           ShowInFileDlg="FALSE"
           Group="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,grpFields;">
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectTypeChoice1;</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectTypeChoice2;</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectTypeChoice3;</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectTypeChoice4;</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
```

This field is referenced in the content type like:

```
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef ID="{E94ED779-2B91-4C68-8B61-6F960FE0018E}" Name="oiplbProjectName"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{70A85923-2950-4469-8AAF-1E90D8DDE7E6}" Name="oiplbAboutProject"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{8326164A-73A9-4DCB-BC72-AF189328FB51}" Name="oiplbOwner" DisplayName="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectOwnerDisplayName;"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{2F30125C-D2C9-459F-9AC5-1796F52C0C4B}" Name="oiplbDepartment" DisplayName="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectOwnerDepartmentDisplayName;" Required="TRUE"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{4E68D20F-C118-421C-8336-A0B1E4BA1706}" Name="oiplbManager" DisplayName="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectManagerDisplayName;"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{F379EB98-E312-44AE-800F-6AAFB781AF55}" Name="oiplbMembers" DisplayName="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbProjectMembersDisplayName;"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{CA82130E-0051-474E-89CC-35CA51AE0FE4}" Name="oiplbStreeringGroup"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{E72347A3-6CCE-4FFB-8BD5-BD2B7DDBF855}" Name="oiplbReferenceGroup"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{0D3060A0-D1A4-4468-B6D3-411839955928}" Name="oiplbProjectType"/>  // Here field is referred.
  <FieldRef ID="{2649184E-DDF5-47FD-8C83-899A8C880BCE}" Name="oiplbProjectStartDate"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{F322DB58-F2A2-4DF8-9AA3-2D6EBE2D94CE}" Name="oiplbProjectEndDate"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{7E146073-5157-48A0-A17C-06E87162573F}" Name="oiplbEstimatedBudgetMoney"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{44AC48F1-4AC1-4C65-ADA8-0074D55C54B6}" Name="oiplbEstimatedBudgetTime"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{0DBB1172-CD48-40BC-96CF-9E8F388EB013}" Name="oiplbProjectStatus"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{DFA037B2-8CCC-4AB9-AF1B-4CC4F6B66B42}" Name="oiplbProjectNumber"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{BDA547BE-D3CB-433D-A372-664158729790}" Name="oiplbSiteUrl" />
  <FieldRef ID="{f3b0adf9-c1a2-4b02-920d-943fba4b3611}" Name="TaxCatchAll"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{8f6b6dd8-9357-4019-8172-966fcd502ed2}" Name="TaxCatchAllLabel"/>
</FieldRefs>
```

After creating a site the list is created successfully and the field `oiplbProjectType` is displayed to the view only, but while creating new entry to the form it is not displayed in the form.

I also checked the columns from the list settings and that field is also available there. What should I do?

Comment: have you tried setting ShowInNewForm="TRUE" in the above code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not displayed because in the field definition you have set ShowInNewForm = "FALSE". Change it to TRUE or remove that atribute and it will show when creating new item.

You may also want to change ShowInEditForm and ShowInFileDlg.

Answer (score 3):

Change this in the above code:

```
      ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
       ShowInNewForm="TRUE"
```